# what is the "unknown error" caused by vba script using zoho sheet

Tags: vba, zoho

What is the "Encountered error at line 32 : unknown error" i'm getting ( line 32 is the line that says "With ws")and how can I remedy? It is not pasting all the data on row two and down on the new sheet, as i was hoping.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub updateCSV()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim desc As Variant, created As Variant, amt As Variant, fee As Variant

'Set Objects
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set newWS = Sheets.Add

'Vars -> Assumes headers are in row 1
desc = Application.Match("Customer Description", ws.Rows(1), 0)
created = Application.Match("Created (UTC)", ws.Rows(1), 0)
amt = Application.Match("Amount", ws.Rows(1), 0)
fee = Application.Match("Fee", ws.Rows(1), 0)
z = 1

'Format newWS
With newWS
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "description"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "date"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Amount"
End With

'Get data from ws
With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Assumes data starts at row 2 and headers are on row 1
    For i = 2 To lr
        z = z + 1
        newWS.Cells(z, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, desc).Value
        newWS.Cells(z, 2).Value = Format(ws.Cells(i, created).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        newWS.Cells(z, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, amt).Value
    Next i
    'Add values back
    For i = 2 To lr
        z = z + 1
        newWS.Cells(z, 1).Value = "stripe fee: " & ws.Cells(i, desc).Value
        newWS.Cells(z, 2).Value = Format(ws.Cells(i, created).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        newWS.Cells(z, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, fee).Value * -1
    Next i
End With

'Fit
newWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Id start by getting rid of `ActiveSheet` and properly qualifying that variable. You're also adding additional sheets to what I assume is a CSV? CSVs are designed to only have 1 worksheet in them - maybe that's causing some kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing "Variant" with "Long" on line 10 the code executed properly.

Original line 10

```
Dim desc As Variant, created As Variant, amt As Variant, fee As Variant
```

with Long:

```
Dim desc As Long, created As Long, amt As Long, fee As Long
```